# Сохранение логина/пароля в браузере после редиректа в expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express

Подскажите, как активировать окно сохранения логина/пароля в браузере, если после этого самого логина у меня происходит редирект.

P.S> Если заменить редирект на res.send, то всё работает, но как тогда вернуть пользователя на предыдущую страницу?

```js
app.put('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  pool.query('SELECT idperson, nickname, email, password FROM person WHERE email=? AND password=?', [req.body.email, req.body.password], function(err, rows, fields, next) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!rows[0]) console.log('Неверные данные');
    else {
      req.session.idperson = rows[0].idperson;
      req.session.nickname = rows[0].nickname;
    }
    res.redirect('back');
  });
});
```

HTML с шаблонизатором(pug)

```html
    form(method="post" action="/login" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded") 
     input(type="email" placeholder="введите email" name="email" required)
     input(type="password" placeholder="введите пароль" name="password" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{6,30}" title="Пароль может содержать только латинские буквы(a-z) и цифры(0-9), от 6 до 30 символов." required)
     input(type="hidden"  name="_method" value="PUT")
     input(type="submit" name="login" value="Войти")
```

Comment: Что означает *активировать окно сохранения логина/пароля в браузере*?

Comment: При успешной авторизации появляется окно сохранения логина/пароля в браузере. В будущем данные не надо будет вводить повторно, всё равно что менеджер паролей.

Comment: Если менеджер паролей не появляется, то надо смотреть на ваш `html`.

Comment: Не пойму как вставить в виде кода :(

        form(method="post" action="/login" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded") 
         input(type="email" placeholder="введите email" name="email" required)
         input(type="password"  required)
         input(type="hidden"  name="_method" value="PUT")
         input(type="submit" name="login" value="Войти")

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте пример `html` в вопрос. Не пишите в комментариях.

Comment: Не сразу нашел кнопку "править", мелкая уж очень.

Comment: Попробуйте задать имя тегу **form**. Браузер должен сам предоставить форму сохранение пароля, не смотря на Ваш редирект.

Comment: не помогает. :(

Comment: Тогда можете сделать, как делают некоторые сайты. После успешной авторизации, перенаправляете на специальную страницу, после загрузки которой пользователь по таймеру, с помощью js, будет перенаправлен на нужную страницу. А вообще странно, у меня никогда такой проблемы не возникало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохранение пароля, как ни странно, происходит только в случае res.send :(

Итого, рабочий код:

```js
   form(id="test" method="post" action="/login") 
     input(type="email" required)
     input(type="password" required)
     input(type="submit"  value="субмит")
```

```html
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  var backurl="Возвращаемся назад <script>window.location = '"+req.header('Referer')+"';</script>";
  res.send(backurl);
});
```